# Getting Error while creating maven project

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I have created new maven project or convert the dynamic web project, but I'm getting a `building work space has encountered a problem` error occurred during the build.

Comment: Paste the error if is possible

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with .metadata. Try deleting it